# Retrieve item from db using ObjectMapper

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm totally new to coding in general, so this is really my first attempt, so don't shoot me if I ask stupid questions ;) Right now I'm having trouble even understanding the the vast world of backend.

So I'm having some problems in my service, and even deciding which way is the best to go, scanning, querying... what?

So I -think- the way to go for me is scanning... I'm having trouble to retrieve an item from the database, based on the id of that item. Retrieving all items works like a charm, and I need something similar for getting one item. I'm getting confused when searching the web, and not really even understanding the difference for example scanfilter, scanexpression? That's why I haven't even come up with a good attempt... but what I need is scan the table and retrieve the item with the matching id. I tried looking at my method for retrieving all searchCases, and implement it for retrieving one it, as it should look quite the same, but no success...

EDITED method a bit: Method I need help with:

```
public SearchCase getSearchCase(String id){
    //this is obviously for a list, but how do I do it for ONE item?
    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> sc = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    sc.put("scId", new AttributeValue().withS(id));

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(searchCaseTableName)
            .withFilterExpression("id = scId");

    ScanResult scanResult = client.scan(scanRequest);
      ?????
    return searchCase;
}
```

As a reference here is the method for retrieving all items, that does work:

```
public List<SearchCase> getSearchCases() {

    final List<SearchCase> cases = new ArrayList<SearchCase>();

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(searchCaseTableName);

    ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
    try {
        for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {
            SearchCase searchCase = mapper.readValue(item.get("payload").getS(), SearchCase.class);
            cases.add(searchCase);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return cases;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been forever, but thought I'd post the correct answer I fought with for a long time back in June. So this was the solution that worked for me for retrieving a single item:

```
public SearchCase getSearchCase(String id) throws Exception  {  

    Table t = db.getTable(searchCaseTableName); 
    GetItemSpec gis = new GetItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey("id", id);      
    Item item = t.getItem(gis);     
    SearchCase searchCase = mapper.readValue(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(item.getJSON("payload").substring(1)), SearchCase.class);

    return searchCase;      
}
```

This method actually took a whole another approach then the way I originally thought I would solve this. So no Scanrequest, but using `GetItemSpec` and `Item` instead. This thus caused some funky backslashes in the JSON, so my frontend wouldn't accept before I ran it through `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson`, otherwise worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm having trouble to retrieve an item from the database, based on the id of that item

If you want to retrieve an item from DynamoDB based on some unique ID, then use [load](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)), which *"Loads an object with the hash key given"*.

Comment: Okay, thanks...But I really can't figure out the syntax based on this, and using google to look at some example gave me no answers either. And don't I need to scan the table to actually find the correct item from the table? Or does load do that as well? As I said, don't shoot me if I ask stupid questions!